# SQL: How to join tables with 1+ millions of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, join, indexing

I want to join two tables ("products" table has 1.5 millions of records) using the following query, but after 15 minutes the query was still running and my pc was overheating (it's a lenovo v330-14ikb with 8gb of RAM), so I stopped it.

I am very new to indexes, and I tried by creating the followings:

- CREATE INDEX customer_id_idx1 ON orders (customer_id)
- CREATE INDEX customer_id_idx2 ON products (customer_id)
- CREATE INDEX customer_id_revenues_idx ON orders(customer_id,revenues)
- CREATE INDEX customer_id_costs_idx ON products(customer_id,costs)

This is the query:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, (SUM(a.revenues) / SUM(b.costs) :: FLOAT) AS roi
FROM orders a
JOIN products b
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
WHERE a.customer_id IN (
    SELECT customer_id FROM (SELECT 
        customer_id,
        COUNT(*) AS n_products
    FROM products
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 5) x
)
GROUP BY a.customer_id  
ORDER BY roi DESC
```

The output should return the ratio of revenues/costs for the top 5 customers by number of products they bought.

I am using pgadmin. Can someone explain me how to speed up and make it compile?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pleaser provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (format text)`** (as you can't run an `explain (analyze)`)  as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: I am trying but unfortunately I am relativetely new to sql and stackoverflow and I don't know what an execution plan is. But I am trying to edit the question like you said

Comment: @123_stack  You just put `explain` in front of the text of your query, and run that.  If you are using a GUI client, there might be a different way, but if you want advice with a specific database client program you would need to tell us what it is.

Comment: @jjanes: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to aggregate twice as far as I can tell.

```
select customer_id, roi
from (
  select o.customer_id, 
         sum(o.revenues) / sum(p.costs)::float as roi, 
         count(*) as n_products
  from orders o
    join products p on o.customer_id = p.customer_id
  group by o.customer_id  
  order by n_products
  limit 5
) t
order by roi desc
```

Alternatively try to aggregate the two tables separately, then join the results:

```
select o.customer_id, o.revenues / p.costs::numeric as roi
from (
  select customer_id, sum(revenues) as revenues
  from orders
  group by customer_id
) o
  join (
    select customer_id, sum(costs) as costs, count(*) n_products
    from products
    group by customer_id
  ) p on p.customer_id = o.customer_id
order by p.n_products desc
limit 5
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried your solution but the problem remains. After several minutes it's still running. Don't know if is a problem with the RAM or with indexes. For example when I try to use the same query but filtering for a specific customer_id (e.g. WHERE customer_id = 779) instead of the subquery it compile in just 5 seconds. But when it comes to filter for the top 5 customers by products it becomes too slow.

Comment: @123_stack: something is wrong here. How many rows does `orders` have?

Comment: orders table has 32 thousands of records, products table has 1.5 millions of records

Comment: @123_stack: I have added another solution.

Comment: Your new solution worked! Can't tell you how thankful I am, thank you su much. Can you explain me what caused the problem? I am new to sql and I still have a lot to learn

Comment: @123_stack: the second solution forces each table to be aggregated individually. If you only have a "few" customers each result will be quite small. When aggregating the result of the join Postgres has to aggregate 1500000 * 35000 rows - I would have expected the optimizer to be smarter than that - but apparently it's not

Comment: Ok I understand now. I was expecting the same, that is why I couldn't figure it out the problem. Now is clear. Thank you very much indeed!